# Splitting a string with spaces into a string with line breaks and displaying in a UILabel

Tags: ios, string, swift

I want to take a string I have i.e. "English Language" and create a string that will display each word on a separate line. Currently I have:

```
    let subjectDesc = "English Language"
    let splitArray = subjectDesc?.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    var finalString = ""
    for item in splitArray! {
        finalString = finalString + item + "\n"
    }
    print("The final string is \(finalString)")
    cell.subjectLabel.text = finalString
```

I have the UILabel Line Breaks mode set to Word Wrap on 2 lines. The label is only displaying the first word. What am I doing wrong here?

Any pointers would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: is there enough space for the label to display 2 line?

Comment: your code prints out `finalString` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should set UILabel's **numberOfLines** to 0 for display multiple lines.